# Est-ce que « Il a laissé tomber Quora digest pour l’écriture » est idiomatique?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, constructions, formulation

Il a laissé tomber Quora digest,  plateforme de questions et de réponses sur laquelle il passait beaucoup de temps à titre de contributeur, pour l’écriture d’un roman.

Il est vrai que la phrase en titre est moins détaillée, mais l’essence de la question demeure la même.

Est-ce qu’il serait préférable de remplacer « laisser tomber pour » par « troquer pour/contre »? Ce qui donnerait, sans reprendre toutes les informations:  Il a troqué Quora digest pour/contre l’écriture d’un roman.

N’hésitez pas à faire travailler vos neurones pour me présenter des propositions plus jolies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il a ***[laissé tomber](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/laisser_tomber)*** est tout à fait idiomatique. Les moteurs de recherche trouvent par exemple des centaines d'occurrences de ***laisse tomber Facebook***.

> J’ai un rapport à l’image et à la photo assez fort. J’ai même laissé tomber Facebook pour ma page privée instagram. ([source](https://www.guillaumeservos.com/victoire-de-blasset/))

Je n'utiliserais pas ***troquer*** dans cette phrase car ce verbe est plus souvent utilisé pour des objets concrets.

Quelques propositions pouvant remplacer *laisser tomber* :

- Il a **délaissé** Quora digest... (soutenu)
- Il a **abandonné** Quora digest...
- Il a **planté** Quora digest... (familier)

PS: La fin de la phrase (*pour l'écriture*) mériterait d'être clarifiée car contribuer à un site passe aussi par l'écriture.

Comment: Pas assez de modifs à faire pour proposer un edit, mais je pense que tu voudras corriger "moteurs de recherchent" par "moteurs de recherche".

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer Merci ! Les moteurs recherchent et trouvent parfois ;-)

Comment: Pas de soucis ^^

Answer (score -2):

Selon le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tomber), dans le présent contexte, comme "laisser tomber" est utilisé avec un cod, la seule définition qui convienne est la suivante.

> **D.** − [Constr. partic. de tomber avec les semi-auxil. faire et laisser]
> **2.** Laisser tomber
> **b)** Fam. **Qqn laisse tomber qqn**. Abandonner quelqu'un dans telle ou telle situation.
> ♦ Je ne peux pas laisser tomber un camarade traqué par les flics (Vailland, Drôle de jeu, 1945, p. 101).
> Dans le domaine affectif et amoureux.
> ♦  On ne laisse pas tomber une belle fille comme vous (Triolet, Prem. accroc, 1945, p. 85).

Quora, qui peut être considéré comme une [personne morale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personne_morale), ne peut pas être "abandonné" dans telle ou telle situation, comme en fait l'adhérent à Quora dépend de cette dernière entité et non vice-versa.

Il est donc certain qu'une autre formule est bien préférable. "Troquer" conviendrait parfaitement.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/troquer)) **B.** − P. ext. [Sans idée de comm.]
> **2.** Abandonner, laisser quelque chose pour autre chose.
> ♦  Il se retourna vers le cabinet de toilette, et aperçut Daniel dans l'entrebâillement des rideaux. Le jeune homme avait troqué sa tunique contre la veste bleutée d'un pyjama (Martin du G., Thib., Été 14, 1936, p. 274).

*Quelques références*

([réf. 1, 1974](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Vie_des_arts/mJtWAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&dq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&printsec=frontcover)) Catherine Bates a troqué la critique d'art pour la rédaction d'un journal intime ; il semble qu'elle ait aussi troqué ses débats publics pour consacrer plus de temps à une oeuvre qu'elle souhaiterait plus intime.

([réf. 2, 2002](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_moi_cr%C3%A9ateur_dans_A_la_recherche_du/BdpcAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&dq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&printsec=frontcover)) Avec succès, le héros a troqué la vie familiale, sous la protection maternelle, pour la vie militaire, non moins réglée et protégée, avec Saint - Loup qui veille sur lui comme un ami et comme une mère.

([réf; 3, 1800](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Simoniana_ou_les_loisirs_d_un_chauffeur/E30-AQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&dq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&printsec=frontcover)) c'est le dictionnaire que nous a envoyé un vieux abbé, qui a troqué ses idées contre des sensations. Il se borne à quatre lettres qui ne contiennent que quatre mots.

([réf. 4, 1997](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_Pays_d_Europe_occidentale_en/rBFPAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&dq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&printsec=frontcover) .. a troqué son poste de responsabilité au sein de la direction de l'OMV pour un poste ministériel. En tant que ministre des Transports, il a négocié les accords de transit avec l'Union européenne.

([réf. 5, 1977](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Serie_sciences_de_l_homme/VC4cAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&dq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&printsec=frontcover)) Aragon, qui fut un des princes de la gratuité, de la disponibilité permanente, de l'art pour l'art, a troqué ces orientations pour d'autres rigoureusement contraires.

([réf. 6, 2005](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Jeune_Afrique_L_intelligent/pO7xAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&dq=%22a+troqu%C3%A9%22&printsec=frontcover)) Dans un pays où l'on a égorgé des bébés et où l'on a éventré des femmes au nom de l'islam, dans une société qui a troqué ses valeurs de solidarité et d'entraide contre la cupidité et la corruption, un prêche débordant de générosité, d'amour ...

Comment: ??? On ne peut pas, d'après toi, **laisser tomber** ses études ?

Comment: @jlliagre Pour le cas de « ses études » je crois que ça va très bien ; ça correspondrait à la définition « Laisser quelque chose baisser, s'arrêter ou disparaître complètement ».

Comment: et quelle différence fais-tu entre *ses études* et *Quora* ?

Comment: @jlliagre La différence ? Quora ne va  ni baisser ni s'arrêter, ni disparaitre.

Comment: *Il a laissé tomber Google pour Bing*. Google va disparaître ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il y a eu un glissement, les gens n'emploient plus cette expression verbale selon un sens plus strict qui était celui que dans un passé récent on lui reconnaissait, à moins que le TLFi ait manqué de détecter cet usage avec un cod.

Comment: Passé récent ? Ce sens existait déjà au XVIIe siècle  https://www.littre.org/definition/tomber#var35

Comment: @jlliagre Le Littré ne s'étend pas beaucoup sur cette expression et mentionne seulement 
 « laisser tomber » puis donne des exemples avec un cod ; Le TLFi donne une exposition plus détaillée et précise: il n'y a de cod (qqn) que dans les sens de "abandonner dans une situation » ; il faut reconnaitre qu'il y a une différence subtile que les gens ne vont pas prendre en compte à moins de lire beaucoup.

Comment: @jlliagre Il est peut-être possible de soutenir que Quora est une chose, mais ça ne me semblait pas être l'idée exacte ; il me semble que c'est l'organisation, les pratiques, le personnel de Quora dont il est question, donc en quelque sorte une personne morale.

Comment: Je laisse tomber...